# Mocking the Children property of DirectoryEntry and the Find method of DirectoryEntries

Tags: .net, unit-testing

What would be a good way to mock the Children property of System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry and the Find method of DirectoryEntries? I'm trying to use the adapter pattern to wrap DirectoryEntry and DirectoryEntries, but I'm not sure how to implement the Children property:

```
public interface IDirectoryEntries
{
    IDirectoryEntry Find(string name);
}

public interface IDirectoryEntry
{
    .. 
    IDirectoryEntries Children { get; }
    ..
}
```

The Children Property if defined like this in the framework:

```
class DirectoryEntry
{
    ..
    public DirectoryEntries Children { get; }
    ..
}
```

Regards,
Frank

Answer (score 1):

Frank!

First of all, for unit-testing right thing to do is to create set of DirectoryEntries specified for your test needs and this naturally leads to how to implement mocks. I've created a simple example of mocking Children property and implementing Find method via [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/):

```
public class TestEntries
{
    public static LinkedList<DirectoryEntry> entries = new LinkedList<DirectoryEntry>();
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var fakeEntry = Isolate.Fake.Instance<DirectoryEntry>();
            Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeEntry.Name).WillReturn("name" + i);
            TestEntries.entries.AddFirst(fakeEntry);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod, Isolated]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var fake1 = Isolate.Fake.Instance<DirectoryEntry>();
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fake1.Children).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(TestEntries.entries);

        var fakeDE = Isolate.Fake.Instance<DirectoryEntries>();
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeDE.Find("")).DoInstead(context =>
        {
            string name = context.Parameters[0] as string;
            foreach (DirectoryEntry entry in TestEntries.entries)
            {
                if (entry.Name.Equals(name))
                    return entry;
            }
            return null;
        });

        Assert.AreEqual("name4", fakeDE.Find("name4").Name);
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you!